# Проверка текущей даты на <=

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Допустим у нас есть дата разблокировки игрока:

```
date_unban = "2023-03-03 15:15:25.501796"
```

Как мне проверить если текущая дата меньше или равняется дате разблокировки?

Что то по типу:

```
if datetime.datetime.now() <= date_unban
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [7]: import datetime

In [8]: date_unban = "2023-03-03 15:15:25.501796"

In [9]: py_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_unban, '%Y-%m-%d %X.%f')

In [10]: py_date
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 3, 15, 15, 25, 501796)

In [11]: datetime.datetime.today() <= py_date
Out[11]: True
```

[datetime.datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Или:

```
In [4]: from dateutil.parser import parse  # pip install python-dateutil

In [5]: parse(date_unban)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 3, 15, 15, 25, 501796)
```